# why scrapy not giving results for one item?

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to get the prices and sellers name in the scrapy but unable to parse them in the correct xpath so that the iterate over them.How to get the correct xpath so that i can retrieve the seller and all the prices?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor



class mspItem(scrapy.Item):
    model_name = scrapy.Field()

    price  = scrapy.Field()
    seller = scrapy.Field()


class criticspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "msp_specs"
    allowed_domains = ["mysmartprice.com/"]
    #### Give array of URLS here, it will generate specs.json, run clean.py on it, mentioning words to include and remove ####
    start_urls = ["http://www.mysmartprice.com/mobile/microsoft-lumia-535-msp5042"]


    def parse(self, response):
        sites = response.xpath('//div[@id="pricetable"]//div[@class="store_pricetable"]')
        items = []
        item = mspItem()
        item['model_name'] = response.xpath('//h2[contains(@class,"priceindia")]/text()').extract()
        for site in sites:

            #item["seller"] = site.xpath("/@data-storename").extract()[0]
            item['price'] = site.xpath('//div[store_price_out]/text()').extract()



            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Updated code --

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor



class mspItem(scrapy.Item):
    model_name = scrapy.Field()

    price  = scrapy.Field()
    seller = scrapy.Field()


class criticspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "msp_specs"
    allowed_domains = ["mysmartprice.com/"]
    #### Give array of URLS here, it will generate specs.json, run clean.py on it, mentioning words to include and remove ####
    start_urls = ["http://www.mysmartprice.com/mobile/microsoft-lumia-535-msp5042"]




    def parse(self, response):
            sites = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"store_pricetable")]')
            items = []
            for site in sites:

                item = mspItem()
                item['model_name'] = response.xpath('//h2[contains(@class,"priceindia")]/text()').extract()
                item['price'] = site.xpath('.//div[@class="store_price"]/text()').extract()



                items.append(item)
            return items
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your first xpath for `sites` is the one wrong , and according to the site's source, it is wrong, because the `div` with class attribute as `'store_pricetable'` is not a child of `div` with class `'pricetable'` .

Also, there are some divs with class as - `'store_pricetable featured_seller'` .

So you may want to use `contains()` here to see get all divs that have `'store_pricetable'` .

And your xpath for `price` is also wrong, as when you do - `//div[store_price_out]` , it is not checking what you intend it to.

You should do - `item['price'] = site.xpath('.//div[@class="store_price"]/text()').extract()` - along with the `dot` at the start to make this xpath relative to current element.

Also, you should recreate item for each loop, do not use the same item object again and again, it overwrites the previous item object.

Example -

```
def parse(self, response):
    sites = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"store_pricetable")]')
    items = []
    for site in sites:

        item = mspItem()
        item['model_name'] = response.xpath('//h2[contains(@class,"priceindia")]/text()').extract()
        item['price'] = site.xpath('.//div[@class="store_price"]/text()').extract()



        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Comment: still not working have you checked I want the price one by one and mobile_name along with it if there are 6 prices then I need 6 time price to be printed along with the different prices

Comment: well that is what this should do, are you getting any error? What are you getting right now?

Comment: I am getting only one output that is a mobile name and the first price in the list

Comment: Are you sure you are using my code? Maybe you didn't fix the second part I talked about where you move mspItem() creation inside the loop?

Comment: I have copy pasted your code ,let me just do it once more

Comment: getting only one result ! plz check on your side the code

Comment: Can you update the question with the latest code you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86851/discussion-between-john-dene-and-anand-s-kumar).